# Spring JPA equivalent to MySql row constructor

Tags: mysql, spring, performance, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Newer versions of MySql have the concept of a [row constructor expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/row-constructor-optimization.html), which enables querying by conditions consisting of a subset of columns matching one of the given entries in a list of tuples; e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE (c1, c2) IN ((1, 1), (2, 2))
```

returns all the entries that have (c1 = 1 and c2 = 1) or (c1 = 2 and c2 = 2).
My question is whether this can be achieved with Spring JPA without using native queries, which would make the code db-provider-dependent.

As a dummy example, say I have a class `Foo` with integer fields `bar` and `baz` and a list of `Foo`s. I want to build an Spring JPA query that would yield all the db entries from table `A(c1, c2, c3)` that match one of my `Foo`s, having `c1 = bar` and `c2 = baz`.

I couldn't find any reference in the Spring docs.

If there is (yet) no solution to this problem, then I'm wondering whether doing a full select then filtering in code is better than doing N queries for individual entries, taking into consideration that the table is small (thousands of entries).

Comment: That's not supported by JPA/Hibernate. If you want to use the full power of SQL with Java I recommend https://www.jooq.org/

Comment: Before MySQL 5.7.3, "row constructors" existed, but were very inefficient.